# How to keep selected value after submit form - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form:

```
<form id="new_user" class="simple_form new_user" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/stats" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>Stats by:</h2>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-group country optional user_country">
                <select id="user_country" class="country optional wabi-form-control select form-control" name="user[country]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
            <input class="btn btn-wabi btn-block" type="submit" value="Show Stats" name="commit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>'
```

Ho do I keep the selected value from `user_country` after `Show Stats` button be click?

Comment: Your anchor doesn't do anything, not even submit the form, so maybe you should show us the code that *does* submit the form ?

Comment: What back-end framework do you use?

Comment: If you LITERALLY want to save the value whenever you click the anchor tag...put a click event listener on the anchor tag, prevent the default behavior, and story the value of the select in a variable. However...That would make no sense looking at the provided mark up.

Comment: As stated above, you aren't actually submitting the form.  I'd change the anchor tag to a button with type="submit".  Now, if you are post submitting then the page is going to refresh (or navigate away).  If you want to then keep the user_country value you will either have to pass the value to the new page or return it back from the server onto the new page.  Both are possible, just depends on how you want to do it.

Comment: @olexity I'm using rails as back-end framwork

Comment: @nurdyguy I got exactly the problem that you said: `if you are post submitting then the page is going to refresh (or navigate away)`. So how to pass value to the new page?

Comment: Do you WANT it to submit?  If so then you should be doing something with the info that is submitted (like saving it to a db).  Then on the next page you would get the info needed back from the db.  This would be a fairly normal way to do this.  Another option might be to set a url variable on the second page and recover the value that way.  What kind of server is this running on?  PHP?

Comment: I use rails @nurdyguy

Answer (score 0):

With PHP, put this into the select/input:

```
value="<?php echo isset($_POST['user_country']) ? $_POST['user_country'] : '' ?>"
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("user_country").value = localStorage.getItem("user_country");

function saveInput() {
    var country = document.getElementById("user_country").value;
    if (country == "") {
        alert("Please select a country first!");
        return false;
    }

    localStorage.setItem("user_country", country);
    alert("Your country has been saved!");

    location.reload();
    return false;
    //return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use AJAX (via jQuery).

```
$('.btn-wabi').on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault():

$.post('/admin/stats')
   .success(function (result) {
        $('#somdivID').html(result);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access that value with jquery:

https://jsfiddle.net/voeo8j7p/

HTML:

```
<form id="new_user" class="simple_form new_user" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/stats" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>Stats by:</h2>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-group country optional user_country">
                <select id="user_country" class="country optional wabi-form-control select form-control" name="user[country]">
    <option value="1">USA</option>
    <option value="2">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="3">Egypt</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
            <a id="showCountryLink" class="btn btn-wabi btn-block">Show Stats</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="current_country_div"></div>
    Current Country: <input id="current_country" val="">
</form>
```

JS:

```
 var current_country = "";

    $('#showCountryLink').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

         console.log("Showing country");
         current_country =  $( "#user_country" ).val();
         $("#current_country_div").html("Current Country: " + current_country);
         $("#current_country").val(current_country);
    });
```